# WebSocket API that connects to ASP.NET Core Backend

Tags: c#, websocket, asp.net-core

I'm writing this API that connects to my ASP.NET Core Cloud App and listens for potential Database changes from my CMS.

The code runs and works fine but I'm not sure if my code is considered "good" or bad.

I've tried to catch all potential Exceptions so that the user of the API can reconnect automaticly because there is no way to restart things manually.

Sorry for the amount of code I provided that's because people that read it can better understand the context.

Is there something that i can improve, or is my coding style a horror :)

Sorry for my English im not a native speaker.

```
    public BackendConnectionService(Uri serverUri, ClientType clientType, bool reconnect) {

        if (!IsValidUri(serverUri)) {
            throw new UriFormatException($"{nameof(serverUri)} is not a valid Uri!");
        }

        Reconnect = reconnect;
        _cloudUri = serverUri;
        Initialize(clientType);
        Connect();
    }

    public bool IsConnected => _webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open;

    public bool Reconnect { get; set; }

    public event BackendChanged OnBackendChanged;
    public delegate void BackendChanged(BackendChangedEventArgs backend);

    public event BackendClosed OnBackendClosed;
    public delegate void BackendClosed();

    public event BackendError OnBackendError;
    public delegate void BackendError(Exception ex);

    public event BackendConnected OnBackendConnected;
    public delegate void BackendConnected();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes Client & Networking
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientType"></param>
    private void Initialize(ClientType clientType) {
        _client = new Client {
            ClientType = clientType
        };

        _webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Establishes Connection with Cloud App
    /// </summary>
    public async void Connect() {
        try {
            await _webSocket.ConnectAsync(_cloudUri, CancellationToken.None);
            await Task.Run(async () => {

                Console.WriteLine($"[{_timeStamp}]: Connected with Cloud App.");
                OnBackendConnected?.Invoke();

                await _webSocket.SendAsync(
                    PrepareMessage($"{nameof(CommandType.ClientRegistration)}{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_client)}"),
                    WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);

                ReadFromSocket();
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{_timeStamp}]: Disconnected with Cloud App.");
            _webSocket = null;
            _cancellationTokenSource = null;
            OnBackendError?.Invoke(ex);

            if(Reconnect) {
                TryToReconnect();
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Could not connect try setting reconnect to true. And subscribe to OnBackendError");
            }
        }
    }

    private async void ReadFromSocket() {

        var receivedBytes = new byte[8192];
        var receivedBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(receivedBytes);

        try {
            while (true) {

                if (_webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Closed) {
                    OnBackendClosed?.Invoke();
                    break;
                }

                var socketResult = await _webSocket.ReceiveAsync(receivedBuffer, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                var bytes = receivedBuffer.Skip(receivedBuffer.Offset).Take(socketResult.Count).ToArray();
                var receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(receivedMessage)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (receivedMessage.StartsWith(nameof(ResponseType.ConnectedClientsResponse))) {
                    _connectedMediaSphereClientsData = receivedMessage;
                    return;
                }

                OnBackendChanged?.Invoke(new BackendChangedEventArgs {
                    JsonBackendData = receivedMessage,
                    ByteBackendData = bytes,
                    BackendChangedDateTime = DateTime.Now
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine($"[{_timeStamp}]: Disconnected with Cloud App.");
            OnBackendError?.Invoke(ex);

            if (Reconnect) {
                TryToReconnect();
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Could not connect try setting reconnect to true. And subscribe to OnBackendError");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect() {
        if (IsConnected) {
            _webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.Empty, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
            Console.WriteLine($"[{_timeStamp}]: Disconnected with Cloud App.");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Pings the Backend
    /// </summary>
    public async Task PingAsync() {
        if (!IsConnected) {
            OnBackendClosed?.Invoke();
            return;
        }

        await Send("ping!");
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Sends data to the Backend
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    public async Task<bool> Send(string data) {
        if (!IsConnected) {
            OnBackendClosed?.Invoke();
            return false;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) return false;

        try {
            await _webSocket.SendAsync(PrepareMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)), WebSocketMessageType.Text,
                true, CancellationToken.None);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            Disconnect();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static ArraySegment<byte> PrepareMessage(string data) {
        var encodedStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        return new ArraySegment<byte>(encodedStr, 0, encodedStr.Length);
    }

    private void TryToReconnect() {

        Console.WriteLine($"[{_timeStamp}]: Trying to reconnect....");
        _webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0));

        if(!Reconnect) {
            return;
        }
        Connect();
    }

    private bool IsValidUri(Uri serverUri) {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(serverUri.OriginalString) && serverUri.OriginalString.Contains("ws");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class**

You have to implement `IDisposable` (assuming `_webSocket` type is derived from `WebSocket` then it implements `IDisposable`).

In your constructor you validate the URI and in `IsValidUri()` you use `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` however you can't create an Uri object with `null` (it will throw `ArgumentNullException`) or empty (it will throw `ArgumentException`) strings.

If `Reconnect` has a public setter then you should consider to remove the `reconnect` parameter from your ctor and I'd strongly suggest to do not perform connection in ctor. Complex operation in ctor are both a pain to debug and astonishing for the caller: constructor should crate an object in a consistent state, it should not perform any other task.

You should consider to name your `async` methods with the `Async` suffix.

**Events and delegates**

You currently have this:

```
public event BackendChanged OnBackendChanged;
public delegate void BackendChanged(BackendChangedEventArgs backend);
```

However you do not need to re-define a new delegate for each event (not to mention that inner classes - and delegates as extension - are often discouraged). You can use `EventHandler<T>`:

```
public event EventHandler<BackendChangedEventArgs> OnBackendChanged;
```

For `OnBackendClosed` similarly:

```
public event EventHandler OnBackendClosed;
```

Note that your event handler now consistently use `EventHandler` pattern for events (not a rule but a suggested design guideline). About [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0eyck3s(v=vs.71).aspx) also note that events should not have `On` prefix. `BackendError` has not its own `*EventArgs` class, introduce it:

```
public event EventHandler<BackendChangedEventArgs> BackendChanged;
public event EventHandler<BackendErrorEventArgs> BackendError;
public event EventHandler BackendConnected;
public event EventHandler BackendClosed;
```

Now we can take a look to their names. Do you need to repeat `Backend*` for each event when they're inside a `BackendConnectionService`? I think they can be simplified making your code both easier to read and less prolix.

I'd also consider to rename `*Closed` in `Disconnected`,  `Changed` to `DataReceived`, and fix typo in `Connectd`:

```
public event EventHandler<BackendDataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;
public event EventHandler<BackendErrorEventArgs> Error;
public event EventHandler Connected;
public event EventHandler Disconnected;
```

**Connection bugs**

Currently if `Connect()` fails you call `TryReconnect()` which calls `Connect()` which if it will fail again will call `TryReconnect()` which...will end with a `StackOverflowException`.

Failed call to `Connect()` will leave the object in an invalid state during the invocation of `Error`. If event handler will check `IsConnected` property to determine if socket is connected then it will get a `NullReferenceException` because `_webSocket` is `null`.

**Connection**

You create a `Task` just to `await` it. Given that `SendAsync` is already awaitable then it makes no sense (unless your purpose is to make `Connected` event asynchronous. Not best option in general and especially in this case because connection might be destroyed while event handler is in execution or after/before that (calls to `SendAsync` and `ReadFromSocket` might fail and socket is then destroyed).

**Disconnection**

You call `CloseAsync()` but you do not wait for it. Why don't you make it `async`?

**Shared considerations**

You're catching `Exception` and that's a bad idea for a number of reasons (do you want to retry connection if you have `AccessViolationException` or `OutOfMemoryException`?) Carefully check which exceptions may be thrown and catch only them (in addition to `AggregateException`).

Do not throw `Exception`. Pick the most proper specific exception or write your own one but be specific or you will force callers to catch `Exception` (we do not like it in our code...don't force them to do it!) Also you may consider (I do not know security implications in your scenario) but you may want to keep reference of original exception:

```
throw new BackendException("...", ex);
```

`OnBackendClosed` (now `Closed`) is invoked when you attempt an operation after closing the backend. It's little bit astonishing, I'd invoke this event after connection has been closed or I'd rename it to something more meaningful (`OperationOnClosedBackend`?) Shouldn't it be an error? I'd expect an `InvalidOperationException`...

Your class is not complete (please do not post partial code) but please check that, if it's `public`, `ClientType` is a read-only property).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to show me that my code is far from good and basically show me the reality I will need time to fully understand your review. Awesome !

Comment: Wait also for other reviews! Well, isn't it why we do code reviews? To make our code little bit better, step by step!

Comment: Sure I will wait for other reviews!